# login CakePHP3.5

Tags: login

He visto videos de como hacer el login pero cuando ya configuro todo al momento de ingresar me dicen nombre o contraseña invalida creo que no me esta leyendo la base de datos no se si me pueden ayudar con el codigo

login.ctp

```
    <div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username and password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

UsersController.php

```
public function login(){

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $users = $this->Auth->identify();
    if ($users) {
        $this->Auth->set($users);
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users']);
    } 
    else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
    }
}
}
public function logout(){
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

}
```

AppController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
  parent::initialize();
  $this->loadComponent('Flash');
  $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
  $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
          'authenticate'=> [
              'Form' => [
                  'fields' => [
                      'username' => 'email',
                      'password' => 'password'

                ] 
            ]
    ],
      'loginAction' => [
          'controller' => 'Users',
          'action' => 'login'
      ]
  ]);


}
```

User.php

```
 protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
    'id'=>false,
];


protected function _setPassword($password)
{
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

Comment: Pon algo de info, configuración, código... sino es bastante complicado poder ayudarte...

Comment: Hola Karina, te sugiero que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funciona StackOverflow Español y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola no se si ahora me puedes ayudar coloco todo este código pero ya cuando corre el programa me dice que la clave o contraseña son incorrectas creo que no esta haciendo la comparación con la base pero no se bien que esa mal

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente **cakephp** es un framework que aún tengo pendiente de aprender.

Lo que sí puedo sugerirte es que le des un repaso al [tutorial de cakephp](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/es/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html), particularmente la sección [Login y Logout](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/es/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#autenticacion-login-y-logout/).

Generalmente cuando no te funciona algo que haces siguiendo un tutorial puede ser que te hallas salteado algún paso o no configurados alguna cosa. También ten en cuenta que el tutorial sea el indicado para la versión de *Cakephp* que utilizas

Saludos.